# iOS - Delete Recurring EKEvent, event appears again

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent, ekeventkit, ekeventstore

I have a recurring event in calendar. I'm delete a single event using this code `[store removeEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&errorThis];` and this methods returns `true` but the event is not  deleted from the calendar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On EKCalendarItem Class reference using the property calendarItemExternalIdentifier you find this

> Recurring event identifiers are the same for all occurrences. If you wish to differentiate between occurrences, you may want to use the start date

So you want delete only a recurrence you have to do something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:calendars];

NSArray *theEvents = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
NSString *recurrenceEventIdentifier;

for(EKEvent * theEvent in theEvents)
{                
    if([theEvent.eventIdentifier isEqualToString: recurrenceEventIdentifier]
        && ![eventStore removeEvent:theEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in removing event: %@",error);
    }

}
```

Your method instead, deletes only the first occurrence. If you want delete all recurring events just change "span" parameter in EKSpanFutureEvents.

EDIT: Now only deletes the matching recurrent event, not everything.

Comment: Then you need also distinguish events with the eventIdentifier otherwise you'll delete all events starting and ending with that dates

Comment: Let say if I have recurrence for Sun, Mon and I want to delete only Mon recurrences. So This wont help.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have only one instance of EKEventStore in singleton pattern in your app :

```
static EKEventStore *eventStore = nil;
+ (EKEventStore *)getEventStoreInstance
{
    if (eventStore == nil){
        @synchronized(self){
            if (eventStore == nil){
                eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
            }
        }
    }
    return(eventStore);
}
```

Comment: How does it make difference? I can delete events that are not recurring.